# How to save file in sd card?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sd-card

As the title, I would like to download a video or music file, then save them to the sd card.
Can I do it ? Please to help me.

Comment: Please also note than in most cases [questions shouldn't include tag in their title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 0):

For now access to SD card is very limited on WP8.0. As it is writted at [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ExternalstorageSDcard):

> Direct access to the SD card is read-only and is limited to file types for which your app has registered to handle with a file association.

**Read-only** - so you can't save files on SD card. There are some rumors that in near future when WP8.1 is released, Apps will have better access to SD card, but for now it is so as it is written.